# Problems starting MySQL on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I am not able to start MySQL server on Mac OS X 10.4.11. MySQL was installed using Macports. MySQL was running fine until it suddenly died without any obvious reason.

When running "mysql", I get the error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through 
socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

If I try to start MySQL manually, I get the following error message:

```
sudo /opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL/opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server: line
159: kill: (636) - No such process
ERROR!
```

In /etc/mysql/my.cnf I have:

```
socket = __PREFIX/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

But the path "opt/local/var/run/mysqld/" does not exist on my system.

I tried to change the socket path to "__PREFIX/var/run/mysql5/ mysqld.sock" (which is where the socket is located). Unfortunately, this did not help either.

Owner and Permissions for /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/ are correctly set.

Any suggestions on how to start MySQL again? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

take dmg from mysql.com, and start it from pref pane

Answer (score 1):

As frx said, you can download the [official distribution](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) for MySQL rather than installing it through ports.

You can also use the wonderfully simple [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/) application to get a MySQL, PHP, and Apache installation all in a neat little self-contained application bundle.